# How to get UITableViewCell subviews in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, subviews

Where can I find `UITableViewCellEditControl` inside `UITableViewCell`. I'm running too old code that needs some UI fix on a quick deadline. I don't have enough time to do it so as I couldn't find any other way.

The app should be supporting from iOS 8.0 and above.

How do I get it?

Current code:

```
for (UIView *subview in [self subviews]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewCellEditControl")]) {
         //this condition will never gets TRUE ...
    }
}
```

Like above, I'm also looking for

1. `UITableViewCellReorderControl`
2. `UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl`
3. `UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl_Legacy`

**Update**:

Found that, I shall access to & `UITableViewCellEditControl`  `UITableViewCellReorderControl` when table view is in editing mode. Don't found anything about `UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl` and `UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl_Legacy`.

Comment: Where you are coding this lines?

Comment: @AshishKakkad, inside `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve once you have that control?

Comment: Not me, last developer have written code to show custom view in place of normal "Delete" "Reorder" cells. @DanielGalasko

Comment: @hagile yes but what are you trying to solve? Maybe it could be achieved easily?

Comment: @DanielGalasko, question updated.

Comment: You still haven't said what it is you are trying to achieve